# SQL Server data file distribution

Tags: sql-server

I am a newbie to SQL Server administration and config. Apologies if I appear to confuse / mix terminologies here.

I am trying to find a way to take a snapshot of current state of database - lock it in some sort of a filegroup/data file - treating it as master data. Track further DML/updates on the data  into a new filegroup /data file.  I dont intend to change the table definitions and only the data can change in the intermediary state.

Is it possible to achieve this in SQL Server?

I am trying to find a solution of creating master snapshot at filesystem level and be able to restore master snapshot.. at any time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Will the result of this be two databases (one snapshot and one tracking), or one database that is an up to date copy of the source database? It's not clear from your question. There are many SQL technologies such as backup/restore, snapshots, mirroring. Is this what you're after? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175511.aspx

Comment: @marc_s I'm still pretty new. How to vote for move?

Comment: @SlavaMurygin: choose "close", then "off-topic because..." and then "belongs on another site" and choose "dba.stackexchange.com"

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. Done.